# Open edX, How to setup CAS login?

Tags: django, authentication, cas, edx, openedx

I need to integrate my CAS into the Open edX platform.
Where can I find the corresponding documentation?
How is the process?

([github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/Setting-Up-External-Authentication](https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/Setting-Up-External-Authentication%20is%20not%20helpful) is not helpful)

Answer (score 0):

It has been a few years since I've used CAS, so I'm hoping my instructions are still valid.  I wrote this blog post to document my steps.

https://dashdrum.com/blog/2013/07/cas-with-django-1-5/

Give it a look, and please feel free to ask questions.